# How to pass Leaf tag to another Leaf tag?

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

Is there a way to passing Leaf tag to another Leaf tag?
For example, in my custom Leaf tag I return some html code:

```
public func run(
        tagTemplate: TagTemplate,
        arguments: ArgumentList) throws -> Node? {

        return .bytes("<span>#(foo)</span>".bytes)
}
```

but in my template `#(foo)` shows as plain text, not render as a Leaf tag, whereas html tags `<span></span>` works properly.

Comment: Maybe you can take the tag in as an argument, render the HTML from it, and then pass in the resulting String using interpolation?